# Run test cases written using TestNG on project

Tags: eclipse, jar, mockito, testng

I have written methods to test one class from my project using mockito. These methods are in different project(Test). I am asked to integrate with my project how can I do? I am asked to create jar file of test project and then integrate. But I dont know how to do that.

I am using TestNG to run that project.

Comment: Use **maven** for managing project and creating project integrated jars.

Comment: How can I use it? Please guide me with this.

Comment: I am using ANT.